Is there any way to save details of page(Route Component) when it switches to another page without using Route/Link?
[Before asking a question, cause I'm Korean, So please understand that I'm not fluent in English writing.]
I'm making a react.js app(for web app), about a conceptual method I will suggest to solve some problems that occured, please tell me some concrete ways if you have good one(s).
In React.js, the most common way to switch page(Route Component) is to use "Route/Link" as far as I know.
(Below is an example.)
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage/>}></Route> 
              <Route path="/newWriting" element={<PostingPage/>}></Route>
              <Route path="/myWriting" element={<MyWritingPage/>}></Route>
              <Route path="/alarm" element={<AlarmPage/>}></Route>

              <Route  path="/article" element={<ArticlePage/>}></Route> {/* exact가 필요한가 ??*/}
              <Route path="/article/patch"element={<PatchPage/>}></Route>
              
              <Route path="/signIn" element={<SignInPage/>}></Route>
              <Route path="/logIn" element={<LogInPage/>}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>

But this method doesn't fit my react app "in some parts, NOT ALL", because when a page is switched to another page, details of previous page[component] are deleted such as scroll position, page(in scroll pagination). Although of course this details can be reloaded if data were stored before page[component] movement (in local storage, browser history or cookie whatever), however in my app, many problems arise with this method. Specifically, the order of information loaded is not consistent which can be said to be a fatal flaw in UX.
I guess "the irregularity in the data loading order due to asynchronouse functions"1) is the cause of the problems[More fundamental reason is probably Pagination, but this must not be excluded.] .
So, a solution for this error I think is this:
Not moving[changing] page (and not using Route/Link "in some parts).
Instead, making the component[I will not use the word "page" anymore because it can be confused with "page in pagination".]  just appear to be switched( in the same URL).
So when a component replaced with another one,  previous component is not deleted[unmounted], but it exists as is, just is invisible. So returning the previous one, details are all maintained without any saving and reloading.
How can the above conceptual description be implemented in React.js code?
can anyone recommend some style or library?
Plus)
can "1)" be solved with "call back"?

it sounds like context  or redux can do your job
